# why taking base class ability is bad

Tags: java, c#, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm reading the [Head First Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do) book.

There is an example that talks about a `Duck` base class:

```
class Duck
{
   public void Quack()
   {
   }

   public void Fly()
   {
   }
}
```

And if I create a child class which cannot fly like:

```
class CantFlyButQuackDuck : Duck
{
    // I can use base Fly() here, but this kind of duck cannot fly!
}
```

So, the book says it's bad because the child class doesn't need to fly, and it has to override nothing.

But if I don't call `Fly()` from the Child class it's okay.  So why does the book say it's bad? I will use this child class in my application like:

```
CantFlyButQuackDuck  myobj= new CantFlyButQuackDuck();
myobj.Quack();
```

Comment: just because you don't call Fly,d oesn't mean you can't call it.
the way those classes are now, your CantFlyButQuackDuck still can fly.

Comment: Then add Print(), Scream() and DestroyTheWorld() methods too. As long as you don't call them...

Comment: You have added the fly capability to the duck which is totally wrong.

Comment: @HenkHolterman pretty much just summed it up.

Comment: @MichaelRiva - flip it on it's head. Rather than asking why it matters if it's there, ask (rather more conscientiously) why you think it should be, and your code will be a lot neater in the long-run.

Comment: Writing classes is not just lumping some properties and methods together. Classes make up an Object model and that should be logical and consistent. When a class ends up with a member it shouldn't have then your model is wrong. Deeply wrong.

Comment: Underlying the principle of object orientation is the concept of "Is A" vs "Has A". Perhaps this might clarify: http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php

Comment: I'd like to refer to [**Composition over inheritance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), which I think applies in this case very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the child class does not share one or more characteristics from the parent class, what reason would there be to make it inherit from the parent class?

The idea behind inheritance is that the properties and methods of the base class must be shared by all its children. In addition to that, each child may have it's own specialised properties and methods, as well as override the inherited methods. In your case, a `Duck`
can `Fly()`, and so must all entities that inherit from it. Just because you don't call that `Fly` on the child does not mean the child doesn't "know" how to `Fly()`.

In fact, this is probably a good scenario to use an interface. This interface will have a method `Quack()`, which your class can implement. Then, while it shares the ability to `Quack` with a `Duck`, it is not able to `Fly()`, and so isn't inheriting from it, while still retaining some shared abilities.

To put this into perspective, let's say you have a `Whistle` which can also `Quack`, but not `Fly`. Since not calling `Fly` on `CantFlyButQuackDuck` seems reasonable going by your logic, it should be equally reasonable on `Whistle`, except that it is blatantly obvious that a `Whistle` is in no way a kind of a `Duck`. That means what you should be looking for is to share certain properties/methods, without implying an "X is a Y" relationship in your model of the world.

Answer (score 2):

Because the way you normally structure classes is by going from least functionality to most functionality, this prevents unintended features from being carried over.

The way you'd normally go by this is like this:

```
class Bird 
{
    public void MakeSound() 
    {
        // insert sound related code here
    }
}
```

Then you inherit based on the needs

```
class Duck : Bird 
{
    public void Fly() 
    {
        // insert flight code here
    }
}

class FlightlessDuck : Bird {}
```

Doing it this way you're absolutely certain that the flightless duck is unable to fly, while the duck IS. Both of these ducks are able to quack (make sound), but only one of them is able to fly.

Doing it the other way you carry the `Fly` method over from the base class, so even if you don't implement any code in the sub-class, you'll still be able to call it, potentially ruining everything.

Even more ideally, you'd add an interface with all the flight related methods, so you're sure that all the birds that need to fly adhere to the same standards. But that's outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Its like giving candy to a kid and telling the kid to not eat it! But hey, the kid still CAN (and most probably WILL once the chance is there :D)!!

**Practically :**
In industry standards, you are often supposed to work on codes that others have written or others are supposed to work on your code. You can't assume that something will never be done!

**Fundamentally :**
It sounds even ridiculous! you are telling the child class that hey, this is your parent and here's what your parent allows you to do. Now like some sincere kid, you choose to NOT use one of these functionalities ... but you still CAN. The duck CAN fly even when its not supposed to fly!

**Code :**

```
CantFlyButQuackDuck  myobj= new CantFlyButQuackDuck();
myobj.Quack();
//so okay if you dont call fly() method.Everything is ok!

// 4months later in the code. Bob comes here and observes ... heck! my duck can Fly ... why not!!
myobj.Fly(); // BOOM!
```

Answer (score 2):

You have three options for overriding `Fly`.

- Don't override, but this would mean that the base fly would be called and it would presumably fly when it wasn't meant to.
- Override with an empty method. This would at least stop the base being called, but the caller gets no feedback from it.
- Override fly and throw an exception. This would not stop the developer calling it, but it would stop fly being called at runtime.

It depends on your situation. Would you like to scratch your head later on wondering why a certain duck isn't flying when you told it to? Or would you like the program to fall over when you attempt to make that certain duck fly?

In practice we would rather have an alternative solution:

At the moment, your base class says that these two methods are cohesive. If a descendant implements one, it **must** implement both or keep the base behaviour. So to solve that we can  [segregate your interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) into cohesive units:

```
interface IFly {
  void Fly();
}
interface IQuack {
  void Quack();
}
```

**Or** we can solve by adding the `fly` method later in the tree:

```
class QuackingDuck
{
   public void Quack()
   {
   }
}

class FlyingDuck : QuackingDuck
{
   public void Fly()
   {
   }
}

class CantFlyButQuackDuck : QuackingDuck
{
}
```

Or you can combine the two techinques.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you choose to call `Fly()` or not, it *can* be called (incorrectly), and *will* be a member of all `CantFlyButQuackDuck` objects, despite the fact this member has no place in the context of an object that can't (and shouldn't be) doing anything with it.

Similar questioning could be applied to many OOP principles. It's just a case of being organised and factoring your code in a way that is scalable and makes sense. Your code will compile and run fine if you extent `Duck` in the way you have there, but you'll run into problems later on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you usually don't design a class hierarchy for yourself but for packages used by others in your team or by customers. And as the child class still has the method someone inevitably will try to use it.

For a real world problem this could lead to a data manipulation that you don't want to happen.
As example: someone could make your ground-bound duck fly, but as it doesn't know  how to land it will get problems feeding.

Answer (score 0):

It's really all about design that makes sense in terms of its use case and it's relationship with other entities. Can you really say that a Duck that cannot fly is a even a Duck?

I would argue that there's been the wrong assumption to begin with - which is that all Ducks can fly, but here, there's a special case where a duck can't actually fly. But that mistake could be easily made as the assumption that ducks can fly is sound.

> But if I don't call Fly() from Child class it's okay. So why does the book say its bad?

It's generally not a great design, because it gives the wrong idea that it can fly just like all other Ducks. That's not to say it's wrong - you can make it work, it's just not ideal and would have to make it very clear in your documentation that Fly doesn't do anything for that particular type of Duck.

Composition over inheritance comes into mind... there's definitely up sides and down sides to inheritance and composition - and certain cases where inheritance is needed i.e. dependency injection - so a generalisation of behaviour.

In this case, you probably want inheritance so that you can iterate through ducks and make them quack or fly together without needing to know what type of ducks there is in the collection of ducks.

A question in the same domain that relates to this question : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/why-avoid-java-inheritance-extends